# Use of Expando in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created a **Custom Fields for Site Resource** in Liferay which is Simple Text Value with default value. I want to display it in my custom portlet.

I have read that we will fetch Custom Fields Value using ExpandoBridge API but I am totally confused. Can we fetch the values using **LocalServiceUtil Class** provided for Expando ?

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to Liferay.

```
    long classNameId = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassNameId(Sites.class.getName());
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay  =(ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);    
    String columnName = "Org. Tag Line";// key
    String tableName = "CUSTOM_FIELDS";
    long siteId = themeDisplay.getSiteGroupId();// userId=classPK
    ExpandoValue expandoObiect=ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), classNameId, tableName, columnName, userId);
    ExpandoValue expandoObiect=ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(companyId, className, tableName, columnName, classPK)
    String value=expandoObiect.getData();
    renderRequest.setAttribute("tagLine", value);
    System.out.println("Field value==>"+value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply get it from group object.
Get site-group from themeDisplay object like `themeDisplay.getSiteGroup()`

And you could get custom-attribute value from group by code below.

```
Group siteGroup=themeDisplay.getSiteGroup();
String value =(String)siteGroup.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("custom-field-name");
```

HTH